# Missing libwvm.so in Android SDK 4.0.3 API(15)

Tags: android, widevine

I am trying to run a Video using VideoView, android emulator throws me with library "unable to open libwvm.so" which should be in /system/lib folder but its missing. Due to libwvm, surfaceflinger cant create buffer. Any suggesions for alternative... Thanks in advance

Comment: Struggling with the same. Seems to be a Widevine (Google's DRM system) library that is not included in the SDK.

Comment: Did you guys find any solution? I've got same on API 17

Comment: Moto G5 and I'm having this same. The .so is not under /system/lib. Yet DRM info says Widevine should be supported.

Answer (score 5):

The widevine library will not work on an emulator. It's by design.

Comment: but from where i download it i have device

Comment: Widevine has been baked into the OS since Android 3.1. As long as your device is widevine certified (and not rooted), you'd be able to make API calls.